# Memory leak issues after page refresh in Safari IPad

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, memory-leaks, safari

This question is more of a sanity check, I cannot logically explain on how this can be happening.
I have application that uses combination of WebSQL, knockout.js and Jquery Mobile UI. It's memory heavy and does have memory leaking (knockout.js and jquery Mobile Ajax navigation doesn't go together well), to the point where after 30 minutes of usage on IPad on Safari application crashes. There is not enough time to fix it all properly till the deadline (don't judge me), so we figured we would not ajax navigate by setting `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;`  every n navigation steps (~5-10), that should terminate all dominated objects and free up the memory - solve the leak. What am I now observing is even after refreshing application, (presumably) memory is still leaking as application is still crashing after prolonged use.
**How can this be? How can memory still be retained after page refresh? How could I force memory to be released?**

Comment: Make sure you are clearing any observableArray or observables that aren't needed. It could also be that your observables are giving off too many value changed notifications. Have you tried memory profiling on a desktop version of Chrome? This can help diagnose memory leaks. Deadline aside, it sounds like the best solution would be to refactor until you fix the memory leak.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you completely, but JQM keeps prior pages cached. Therefore it could be that there are some remnants of pages in the JQM cache. Have you tried clear the previous page from the DOM each time you navigate to a new page? Thus tidying up after yourself just for debugging purposes?

Comment: With something like this: $($.mobile.pageContainer).live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
});
$.mobile.changePage('UI/demo/login.html')

Comment: @PhillHealey I was doing wipeout of all elements traversing the DOM tree, unbinding knockout.js nodes and removing eventhadlers with .off(). But it was still crashing so then the idea to refresh the page came. Do you think it makes sense to combine the two?

Comment: @LIUFA Since your still having issues, I don't see why not. It doesn't sound like it can get any worse. Another option might be to load everypage 'afresh' rather than going via AJAX and then clearing out the page cache, etc. You could do this by traversing pages with 'window.location= newpage' or setting ajax to off on all links using either 'data-ajax = false' or 'rel=external'. It'd certainly be more efficient to do it that way. That should definitely load every page directly and thus not have any js hangovers.

Comment: It'd also be more efficient than ajax traversing and then clearing out the cache. You would of course lose any ajax transitions, and may need to rethink some other elements of your JS/JQuery & JQM events though.

Comment: @PhillHealey Thanks I will test it with disabled ajax navigation.

Comment: @Omar $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;

Comment: `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` disables Ajax. You refresh using `.reload()`? Are you using _Single page_ or _Multi-Page_ mode?

Comment: `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` should be called before jQM is loaded. So I dont think that Ajax is being disabled during transitions.

Comment: @Omar I am sorry I have lied in my previous answer about muti-page it seems I am using Single-page mode. How does this affect the situation?

Comment: @LIUFA As Omar says, using '$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;' isnt expressly loading pages directly. It's simply saying dont use ajax. But depending on your events and how and where you use it, this might not be having any effect. Best try one of the method I suggested or, load pages via ajax, to give the ajax transitions then refresh the page. Although that could just mask the real issues.

Comment: Single page model with ajax disabled, all pages are loaded via HTTP. It's like browsing a website normally.

Comment: @PhillHealey I will do the page .reload() and let you know the result, thanks guys.